# Tabbed activity se para al iniciar la aplicación en Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Estoy creando una aplicación en **Android** y tengo una actividad con unas pestañas, pero cuando inicio la aplicación, se detiene y me dice que La aplicación se ha detenido. Mi **código** es este:

**Adaptador de las pestañas:**

```
package com.example.user;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.*;

public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> frags = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        frags.add(fragment);
        titles.add(title);
    }

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){ super(fragmentManager);}

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {return titles.get(position);}

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {return frags.get(position);}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {return frags.size();}
}
```

**Manifiesto:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".tab" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**Actividad:**

```
package com.example.user;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class tab extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TabAdapter tabAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ActionBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        bar = getSupportActionBar();

        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);
        setup(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setup(ViewPager viewPager) {
        tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        tabAdapter.addFragment(new tab_horari(), "Horaris");
        tabAdapter.addFragment(new tab_clients(), "Clients");
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
    }
}
```

**Fragmento 1:**

```
public class tab_horari extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_horari, container, false);

        Button btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

**Fragmento 2:**

```
public class tab_clients extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_clients, container, false);

        Button btn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Tab 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

**Log:**

```
08-04 20:03:59.626 19444-19444/com.gerrysoft.totpilates D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
08-04 20:03:59.626 19444-19444/com.gerrysoft.totpilates D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
08-04 20:03:59.916 19444-19444/com.gerrysoft.totpilates D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-04 20:03:59.927 19444-19444/com.gerrysoft.totpilates E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.gerrysoft.totpilates, PID: 19444
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gerrysoft.totpilates/com.gerrysoft.totpilates.tab}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3150)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                                                          at com.gerrysoft.totpilates.tab.onCreate(tab.java:31)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3103)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1734) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6934) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
08-04 20:04:05.262 19444-19444/com.gerrysoft.totpilates I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19444 SIG: 9
```

Comment: hiciste `debug` de tu aplicación?

Comment: No, y solo lo puedo probar en móviles reales porque tengo 4gb de ram y el emulador es muy lento

Comment: haz `debug` desde el celular entonces. (si es android studio, está al lado derecho del Rayito)

Comment: Vale, lo haré en cuanto pueda y lo subiré aquí.

Comment: mínimo consigue averiguar tu exepción, y en que línea lo arroja, sería muchísimo más fácil encontrar tu error :)

Comment: Si deseas desarrollar en Android te recomiendo revises el uso del [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html), es importante para evitar tratar de estar adivinando infinidad de posibles causas, saludos.

Comment: Ya he puesto los resultados

Comment: @GerryStudios gracias, dentro del layout activity_tab.xml que carga la activity no estas usando: <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar , cambialo!:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java.lang.ClassCastException se lanza cuando se intenta relacionar (convertir, "castear") un objeto de una clase con algún objeto de otra clase.

En este caso es un error relacionar el widget Toolbar del xml con tu objeto de la clase Toolbar que tienes en tu Actividad.java, ya que existe android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar y android.widget.Toolbar

Verifica que la definición de la toolbar en tu archivo actividad.xml sea así:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

O bien crea y relaciona el objeto de tipo Toolbar de tu clase de esta forma.

```
android.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya me funciona

Answer (score 1):

El error reportado es :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.gerrysoft.totpilates/com.gerrysoft.totpilates.tab}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Regularmente sucede cuando no usas el `import` adecuado, actualmente es recomendable usar la clase de la biblioteca de compatibilidad:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

En este caso estas usando el import adecuado y obtienes la referencia del toolbar en el layout:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Pero dentro del layout `activity_tab.xml` seguramente no estas usando

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

---

más información :

[Configuración de la barra de app](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)